How can I fix this UV mapping
How can I fix the UV where it shows the surrounding borders are double? its like a tiled pattern.




pls provide blend file because we don't know how your uv mapping/geometry looks like.thx.



No need for a file. Your texture has no gap between the circles and the outer border, while inbetween them there are gaps. So when this texture gets tiled, where two borders meet there is no gap between circles. You need to expand the border to (gap/2) pixels all around, so that when they tile there is (gap/2)+(gap/2) = gap pixels between the circles.

What you really want to do in a situations like this is to stop wasting RAM or VRAM without any good reason with repeating the same information in the texture image. It's one dot, just use one. You can have way higher resolution of the texture and use way less memory at the same time.

Going procedural with this is also extremely easy since Voronoi nodes got updated with all the fancy new features a while ago now. Just one Voronoi node with Randomness set to 0 and a Math node after that in Less/Greater than mode.

Hi Martynas. I did a node set up, like your nodes, I also added a bump node, but not getting any result.
https://ibb.co/p1c9jVK

Here is an exaggerated example of what your texture looks like, let's say it is just 4 circles, each one 130 pixels in diameter with a gap of 70 pixels between them. If you leave no gap to the left, right, top and bottom and your tile is therefore 330 × 330 pixels, then tiling it results in this:

But if you now expand the texture around the border by 70/2 pixels = 35 pixels so that the tile is now 400 × 400 pixels, the tiling result looks like this:


Of course Gordon is right - as he mentioned in the comments, you can improve your png and add the correct border.
But there are nearly always multiple solutions to one problem.
So another way is this:


It is not the most elegant solution, but it works (if that counts to you) and if you don't wanna edit your displacement png.
So first change the image texture to single image.
Add the nodes as you can see in the shader node tree.
What it essentially does is "rebuilding" the repeating pattern manually "before" the image texture. Therefore i am using the modulo and the scale of the mapping.
The scale after the combine node is just to make the use of the combine node easier by sliding the values.
By playing around and eyeballing you can get other scale values (changing scale in mapping and changing values in combine xyz)


Hi guys, thanks to both of you for your information. Gordons reply got me thinking, so I tried this method in Illustrator, as seen the in the screenshot, by cutting off the edges off the circles, so they can adjoin in the UV mapping, and the result was good. Also with Chris's method with the node set up, of course, I saved this screenshot if I need another method which requires only Nodes.
https://ibb.co/hcBymDm
https://ibb.co/Ky4xTpS
